# PHP How do I disable com_dotnet?

Tags: php, .net

Simple question, I hope. In php, how can I disable com_dotnet. It's showing up in phpinfo(); I'm running PHP Version 5.3.14 through Zend/Apache on Windows 7 Enterprise. In the php.ini file I see an item for com.allow_dcom = true, but it's commented out.

Comment: You may have to recompile PHP without DOTNET.  I don't see a configuration option specifically for DOTNET.

Comment: Setting com.allow_decom = false has no effect.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!  Building PHP on Windows is a real hassle.  :-)

Comment: Better read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php - Just install PHP 5.3.15 instead and you can disable it by not loading the extension .dll file in your ini - Related: [Bug #62146 com_dotnet cannot be built shared](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62146)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP had a bug in the past that the [COM Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) could not be build as a shared extension. This has been fixed recently. The issue is: [Bug #62146 com_dotnet cannot be built shared](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62146).

So if you install PHP 5.3.15 you can disable it by not loading the .dll extension file. This is also outlined in the user-comments on [COM Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php).

```
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dot_net.dll
```

If you can not upgrade PHP then you will see the bug and you can not disable the extension.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Zend server and the recommended course of action is to wait for them to release updates. No 5.3.15 yet.